# How to calculate time difference

Tags: php

```
$to = strtotime("2008-12-13 10:42:00");
$from = strtotime("2008-12-13 10:21:00");
echo round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 60,2). " minute";
echo round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 3600,2). " hours";
```

It is working good when I convert into minutes, but when converting into hours it's not giving the correct output.

Comment: Please explain: "it's not giving the correct output". What were you expecting, what did you get?

Answer (score 0):

Try This
Source : http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2008-12-13 10:42:00');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2008-12-13 10:21:00');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%h hour');
echo $interval->format('%R%i minute');
?>
```

Use appropriate format from here http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$from = new DateTime('2008-12-13 10:21:00');
$to = new DateTime('2008-12-13 10:42:00');

$diff = $to->diff($from);
$hours = $diff->h;//hours
$mins = $diff->i;//minutes
echo $hours.':'.$mins;
```

With the above the $diff is an array containing these keys:

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 0
    [d] => 0
    [h] => 0
    [i] => 21
    [s] => 0
    [weekday] => 0
    [weekday_behavior] => 0
    [first_last_day_of] => 0
    [invert] => 1
    [days] => 0
    [special_type] => 0
    [special_amount] => 0
    [have_weekday_relative] => 0
    [have_special_relative] => 0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the "correct output" that you are expecting.

```
21 minute
0.35 hours
```

The difference is 21 minutes, so 0.35h is correct.

Anyways your code is wrong, you are using `$from_time` and `$to_time` instead of `$to` and `$from`